# Set height of all cells using specific identifier?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, uitableview

I have a table view which has prototype cells. How do I set the height of all cells using a specific identifier? For example, I have two cells; one with an idenfier of `"cell10"` and another with the identifier `"cell50"`. How do I set it so all cells with the identifier `"cell10"` have a height of 10 while all cells with the identifier `"cell50"` have a height of 50? Any answers are appreciated. (By the way, I am using Swift 2.)

Comment: Are you using different identifiers for all the cells in table view?

Comment: Each cell is being created/dequeued based on your datasource. This datasource must indicate whether to use `cell10` or `cell50` using the index path. Just use the same information to determine which height to return based on whether you would use a `cell10` or `cell50` for that index path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within heightForRowAtIndexPath() you can call cellForRowAtIndexPath(). 
Once you have the cell then you can call reuseIdentifier  to get its identifier.
Then return either 10 or 50 based on the identifier

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how to do it in swift but in objective C i would do the following things-

Implement the following function of tableview-

```
    -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    //your custom cell
         UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

         if(cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"cell10"){
            return 10;
         }else{
            return 50;
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

heightForRowAtIndexPath called first and then cellForRowAtIndexPath get called. So it may be possible that in heightForRowAtIndexPath method we do not get cell or some inconsistency.

You must have some value or field on basis of which you can specify or differentiate cell identifier. You have array of models which may contain that value. 
So in heightForRowAtIndexPath(), you can get model from datasource array for that indexpath using objectAtIndex method, and check which type it is and depending on that return the height.

This will help in every case. It is working for me.